# How to add caption field for every image before submit it

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my project I have a product gallery.In admin panel user needs to add caption for every image.in fact, he/she selects image or images and after one by one he/she add a caption for every image.

**Note:** I didn't save images in database I've kept image name in database.

what is your Idea?

```
 public class ProductGallery
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ThumbImageName { get; set; }
        public string LargeImageName { get; set; }
        public string CaptionImage { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I see you have a `CaptionImage` property. Store the caption in that ???

Comment: @Shyju,Yes . it's a property for keeping caption for every image.

Comment: Then what is your problem ? Question ? Be more specific

Comment: Sorry ! I do not understand what you wrote in your last comment!

Comment: @Shyju,In fact, I want to know how to determine every image for a caption.

Comment: Read the table records and use the CaptionImage property value as needed for the associated image.

Comment: @Shyju,I'm sorry ,I changed my title of question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159766/discussion-between-behnam-farhadi-and-shyju).